# Combine a Read and Parse text.txt

Tags: java, parsing

**Problem:** I can't parse my file test.txt, by spaces. I can 1) read text files, and I can 2) parse strings, but I cannot connect the two and parse a text file! My purpose is to learn how to analyze text files. This is a simplified approach to that.

**Progress:** Thus far, I can read test.txt using FileReader and BufferedReader, and print it to console. Further, I can parse simple String variables. The individual operations run, but I'm struggling with parsing an actual text file. I believe this is because my test.txt is stored in the buffer, and after I .close() it, I can't print it.

**Text File Content:**
This is a 
text file created, only
for testing purposes.

**Code:**

```java
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

    //create method to split text file, call this from main
    public void splitIt(String toTest)
    {
        String[] result = toTest.split(" ");

        for (String piece:result)
        {
            //loop through the array and print each piece
            System.out.print(piece);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create readfile method    
        try
        {
            File test = new File("C:\\final\\test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(test);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line = null;

            //While there are still lines to be read, read and print them
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                splitIt(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        }

        //Catch those errors!
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

//      readFileMethod a = new readFileMethod(line);
        System.out.println(a.splitIt());

    }

}
```

Preemptive thank you for your sharing your knowledge. Many posts on reading and parsing have been solved here on SO, but I've not the understanding to implement others' solutions. Please excuse me, I've only been learning Java a few months and still struggle with the basics.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve and put the text file content too.

Comment: Hey root, I've added the text file content (just simple placeholder text), and described my purpose. I want to have each word in the text document separated by lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Scary Wombat and your code, i made some changes.
It should now print the Line that is being read in and each word that is separated by space.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

    //create method to split text file, call this from main
    public static void splitIt(String toTest)
    {
        String[] result = toTest.split(" ");

        for (String piece:result)
        {
            //loop through the array and print each piece
            System.out.println(piece);

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create readfile method
        try
        {
            File test = new File("C:\\final\\test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(test);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line = null;

            //While there are still lines to be read, read and print them
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line); // print the current line
                splitIt(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        }

        //Catch those errors!
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this worked flawlessly. I appreciate the complete working code :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat erm...I really do appreciate both of your answers. Why downvote root for providing a complete solution? And regarding the sarcastic learning comment, I've read a few hundred pages of Java since posting this question and have substantially increased my understanding. As such, I've rewritten the code several times from scratch. I don't know why you'd take such a cheap shot at someone who once stood in the same shoes as you...but it doesn't matter. I appreciate this community of learners and teachers nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Ok lets make the splitting into a mthod

```
private static void splitIt (String toTest) {

  String[] result = toTest.split(" ");

  for (String piece:result)
  {
      //loop through the array and print each piece.
      System.out.println(piece);
  }
}
```

then you can call it from within

```
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        splitIt (line);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Scary Wombat, I've *attempted* to incorporate your answer into my code block, but I'm still hampered by the fact that I'm calling a non-static from within the static main (I believe). A few hours of work and 30 pages of reading hasn't resulted in any solution, but it's obvious this is a common beginner problem :( Have you any clues?

Comment: @PizzaAndCode Since `splitIt` is not a static method, it would require the class it is contained in to be Instantiated first (make a new object of the class). You _could_ create a new object of `ReadFile` within main and then call the method from that object itself. But it's probably easiest (and in this case make more sense) to just make `splitIt` a static method.

Comment: @kunruh Thanks for your comment.  I have edited my answer to make this method `static`